# Nested if formula (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I am trying to write a formula where if cell (J$4) = 1120 then it would run one statement, whereas if cell (J$4) = 1120s it would run another.  I am using index-match to lookup the appropriate value.  However, I can't seem to get my formula to work and I was wondering if you guys can find my error.  The error is 'you've entered too many arguments for this function'.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(J$4="1120S",INDEX(B1HY3!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH("L 22a",B1HY3!$F$3:$F$300,0),5),IF(J$4=1120,INDEX(B1HY3!$A$3:$f$300,MATCH("L 22a",B1HY3!$f$3:$f$300,0),5)+INDEX(B1HY3!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH("L 22b",B1HY3!$F$3:$F$300,0),5),0),0)
```

Comment: This is a formula right, not in VBA?

Comment: You are missing a ')' change the end to `...,0),5),0)),0)`

Comment: =IFERROR(IF(J$4="1120S",INDEX(B1HY3!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH("L 22a",B1HY3!$F$3:$F$300,0),5),IF(J$4=1120,INDEX(B1HY3!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH("L 22a",B1HY3!$F$3:$F$300,0),5)+INDEX(B1HY3!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH("L 22b",B1HY3!$F$3:$F$300,0),5),0)),0)

Comment: @Rdster yes its a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always try to follow parentheses' colors it is quite useful when handling with large formulas,furthermore try always to evaluate your formulas to check where the error is.
It worked for me:

```
=IFERROR(IF(J$4="1120S",INDEX(B1HY3!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH("L 22a",B1HY3!$F$3:$F$300,0),5),IF(J$4=1120,INDEX(B1HY3!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH("L 22a",B1HY3!$F$3:$F$300,0),5)+INDEX(B1HY3!$A$3:$F$300,MATCH("L 22b",B1HY3!$F$3:$F$300,0),5))),0)
```

It was nessesary to close the parenthesis of the second `if`

Comment: also the use of F9 key to show sectional results.  So `if(a=b,c,d)`  highlighting the a=b  and pressing F9 would show TRUE/FALSE  where in yours the F9 came back saying missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: no probs, remember to make sure it returns back to the formula after though as it can leave the result in place.